# How to make all objects into one array and remove duplicates?

Tags: javascript

I have this object, and I want Remove duplicates and make it into one array

```
var sports = [
  ['basketball','fotball','racing'],
  ['fotball','basketball','swimming'],
];
```

What is the best way to get it like this:

```
['basketball','fotball','racing','swimming'],
```

The `flat()` will make the sports into one array, and is probably the best option here?
Just have to remove the duplicates any tips?

Comment: Convert the flattened array to a Set, then convert that back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

use below:

```
[...new Set(sports.flat())]
```

Here sports.flat() flatten out the array. [See the doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

and new Set() will make them unique. [See the doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 